# Limit/Count number of chracters in TextArea using jquery

Tags: jquery, count, textarea

How to **count** the characters what entered in text area box?

I have textbox like the following,

```
 <%: Html.TextArea("Message", "", new { @title = "Enter the Message" })%>
```

My maximum count is 160 characters. If the characters gettng exceeds it should show the count of the characters / 2 messages. How to count the charaters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a jquery event handling method:

**Markup**:

```
<%: Html.TextArea("Message", "", new { @id = "mytextarea", @title = "Enter the Message" })%>    
<div id="charNum"></div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#mytextarea').keyup(function(){          
      var len = $(this).val().length;
      if (len >= 160) {
          var output = $(this).val().substring(0, 160);
          $(this).val(output);
      } else {
          $('#charNum').html(160 - len);
      }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/3rqVN/)**

Comment: If i use keyup function in textarea it is not taking the function. shoiwng error like `count char is not defined`

Comment: no, i am going to try that. but ive changed the previous method into `$('#Message').keyup(function())` like wise. still it is not calculate the len variable. shoiwng an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined `

Comment: I will update my answer to include only the last method which I believe should be the working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since u haven't posted any code i would tell u how to go forward about implementing this..
simple attach a script on `keyup` to the textarea like

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
        console.log($(this).val().length);
});
```

And `$(this).val().length` should give you the length of the text entered. Then you can implement the way you want it to...
Hope it helps